# Missing initramfs images on Fedora Rawhide

Tags: fedora

When using [Fedora Rawhide](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/Rawhide) I'm missing the initramfs images in `/boot`. I have the file `initramfs-3.12.6-300.fc20.x86_64.img` for my latest kernel installed with Fedora 20. I don't have a initramfs image with Fedora Rawhide.

Why is the initramfs images missing and how can I generate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wth [Dracut](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Dracut) it is possible to generate initramfs images on Fedora. The configuration of Dracut is available in `/etc/dracut.conf`. To overwrite an existing initramfs image add the parameter `--force`.

`dracut /boot/initramfs-3.15.0-1.fc21.x86_64.img 3.15.0-1.fc21.x86_64`

The Grub2 configuration should be regenerated afterward using `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`.

To simplify your life use the following script.

```
#!/bin/sh

# author: Christian Berendt <mail@cberendt.net>

set -x

for kernel in $(find /boot/vmlinuz*); do
    version=$(basename $kernel)
    version=${version#*-}
    if [ ! -e /boot/initramfs-$version.img ]; then
        sudo /usr/bin/dracut /boot/initramfs-$version.img $version
    fi
done

for image in $(find /boot/initramfs*); do
    version=${image%.img}
    version=${version#*initramfs-}
    if [ ! -e /boot/vmlinuz-$version ]; then
        sudo rm $image
    fi
done

sudo /usr/sbin/grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```